# How to merge two matrices with differing number of rows

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Lets say i have 2 matrices looking like this:

```
structure(c(0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211), .Dim = c(14L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(c("ch5_98500001", "ch5_99500001", "ch5_100500001", 
"ch5_101500001", "ch5_102500001", "ch5_103500001", "ch5_104500001", 
"ch5_105500001", "ch5_106500001", "ch5_110500001", "ch5_111500001", 
"ch5_112500001", "ch5_113500001", "ch5_114500001"), "loh"))
                    loh
ch5_98500001  0.3157895
ch5_99500001  0.3157895
ch5_100500001 0.3157895
ch5_101500001 0.3157895
ch5_102500001 0.3157895
ch5_103500001 0.3157895

structure(c(0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 
0.315789473684211, 0.315789473684211, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 
0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579, 0.368421052631579
), .Dim = c(83L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("ch8_20500001", "ch8_21500001", 
"ch8_22500001", "ch8_23500001", "ch8_24500001", "ch8_25500001", 
"ch8_26500001", "ch8_27500001", "ch8_28500001", "ch18_500001", 
"ch18_1500001", "ch18_2500001", "ch18_3500001", "ch18_4500001", 
"ch18_5500001", "ch18_6500001", "ch18_7500001", "ch18_8500001", 
"ch18_9500001", "ch18_10500001", "ch18_11500001", "ch18_12500001", 
"ch18_13500001", "ch18_14500001", "ch18_15500001", "ch18_16500001", 
"ch18_17500001", "ch18_18500001", "ch18_19500001", "ch18_20500001", 
"ch18_21500001", "ch18_24500001", "ch18_25500001", "ch18_26500001", 
"ch18_27500001", "ch18_28500001", "ch18_29500001", "ch18_30500001", 
"ch18_31500001", "ch18_32500001", "ch18_33500001", "ch18_34500001", 
"ch18_35500001", "ch18_36500001", "ch18_37500001", "ch18_38500001", 
"ch18_39500001", "ch18_40500001", "ch18_41500001", "ch18_42500001", 
"ch18_43500001", "ch18_44500001", "ch18_45500001", "ch18_46500001", 
"ch18_47500001", "ch18_48500001", "ch18_49500001", "ch18_50500001", 
"ch18_51500001", "ch18_52500001", "ch18_53500001", "ch18_54500001", 
"ch18_55500001", "ch18_56500001", "ch18_57500001", "ch18_58500001", 
"ch18_59500001", "ch18_60500001", "ch18_61500001", "ch18_62500001", 
"ch18_63500001", "ch18_64500001", "ch18_65500001", "ch18_66500001", 
"ch18_67500001", "ch18_68500001", "ch18_69500001", "ch18_70500001", 
"ch18_71500001", "ch18_72500001", "ch18_73500001", "ch18_74500001", 
"ch18_75500001"), "loss"))
                  loss
ch8_20500001 0.3157895
ch8_21500001 0.3157895
ch8_22500001 0.3157895
ch8_23500001 0.3157895
ch8_24500001 0.3157895
ch8_25500001 0.3157895
ch8_26500001 0.3157895
ch8_27500001 0.3157895
ch8_28500001 0.3157895
ch18_500001  0.3157895
ch18_1500001 0.3157895
ch18_2500001 0.3157895
```

And i want them to merge in 1 data.frame or matrix just so that i have an overview and there's no need for switching between the files. But the problem solving this seems a bit harder than just use `data.frame`.

Anyone any idea how not to get the problem of differing row lengths?

Comment: @jem77bfp Is this also possible with 3 or more frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 merge(as.data.frame(loss), as.data.frame(loh), by="row.names")
```

but it gives empty data frame, as there are no row names in both of your matrices that match. You can also do

```
 merge(as.data.frame(loss), as.data.frame(loh), by="row.names", all=TRUE)
```

For multiple data frames I would use function [Reduce](http://www.r-bloggers.com/applying-a-function-successively-in-r/).

```
 Reduce(merge, list(data1, ..., dataN)))
```

Make sure you pass the `by` argument to `merge` as well.